# Async Notifications in react-native

Tags: android, push-notification, react-native

ok so I have an app in react native which retrieves the information from an api. Now the api whenever it has data to send will send the data to the device and I want my app to be always running in background so as to receive the response from the api. API can send data anytime so I want to show the user data received as soon as a message arrives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into **Push Notifications**. You can't guarantee that your app will always be running in the background, but Push Notifications allow you to send data to a user's phone even when the app isn't running. Once the user opens the notification you can perform some action, based on the data sent with the notification.

A good React Native component for push notifications is [React Native Push Notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification), which offers cross-platform notifications. Once you have this implemented you can create a handler which calls your API when the app is opened from a notification.

Comment: There should be some server side changes as well right?

Comment: Also if you have an implementation example it would be great I don't understand where this component registers and uses all the information

Comment: Yep you'll need a method by which to actually _send_ the notifications (via APN or GCM). The [RN push notification docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#content) explain the system quite well, and [this Parse guide](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial/tree/master/iOS) shows how to configure the entitlements/certs required for actually sending them.